# Can i use Emberjs + PHP + MySQL + Firebase > Emberjs

Tags: laravel, firebase, ember.js, ember-data, google-cloud-firestore

Our platform is a collaborative web design and marketing platform.

We are using Ember js on the frontend that speaks to our backend(laravel) via Jsonpatch.

Our DB is MySQL, so it is relational.

This solution works fine for us, but there is a new need to bring in the collaborative way of working in our app.

So real time updates are needed!

We also use Firebase for some event driven frontend data updates, but now we are thinking to migrate completely to firebase.

Again, our DB is relational but Firebase is non-relational.  So what will be the best way to go with in our case?

Is there a way for our backend to still work for backend validations and permission checks for DB .read and .write  operations for different user types and user groups.

So in this case we will have Emberjs - Laravel - Mysql - Firebase - Emberjs, so that our frontend will send save calls to our backend, which will normally update the mysql if the user has enough permissions, which will then let Firebase know about the changes and push that data back to Emberjs.

Do you think this is a good idea or do you have any other recommendation?

Thank you so much!

Gev

Comment: You might want to take questions asking for opinions and recommendations to Quora instead of Stack Overflow.  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/02/best-help-for-firebase-support.html